# How remote connection with IP addres and name of server

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have IP addres, names of server (three server on 1 IP), login and password. Server is Windows Server 2012.

How I can connect to remote desktop (I have access to OS Windows 7)?

Comment: Be more specific, which 3 servers, windows? In all versions of windows you have `mstsc.exe`, which is standard remote desktop client, for other OS search for RDP client. If you want 3 servers on one IP, then you need to setup a RDP Gateway or change service port on two of them. :)

Comment: I am client - I can connect to remote servers. Servers (all) is on platform Windows Server 2012. So, administrator have to do configuration for next ports?

Comment: In that case follow [@Dave-Rook's](http://superuser.com/a/678232/166160) answer and add your server's IP to `Computer:` column.

Comment: Or ask your admin for `RPD File` with settings. That way you only need to run that file, without setting anything (on Windows).

Comment: What do you mean with "three Server on 1 IP"? If you don't know how to do a remote Desktop Connection, how come you Need to remote connect to a Server? What do you want to do there? Remote Desktop to a Server is for admins - and those should not ask such trivial stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use RDP (remote desktop) you need to ensure it's enabled on the remote machine(s) but I'll assume it is. If not, then search on-line, it's been covered many thousands of times before.

However, to find it on your machine you have two choices

1. Click start and type mstsc.exe and press enter

   Click start, All programs, Accessories, Remote desktop connection.

Please note, RDP, remote desktop protocol and remote desktop connection are typically (whether incorrectly or not) interchangeable (in regards to terms).

When the RDP window is open, click more options. Here, you will have the option to enter the computer (name or IP address), the username (if using a domain, include the domain first, like domain\username). You will also have the option to save the password. You can also save these settings to the desktop (or where ever you like) so next time, you just double click on it. [image]